# looking for solution of c++ member function override (non virtual)

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I've two classes:

```
struct A {

    template <typename T>
    void print(T& t){ 
        // do sth specific for A
    }
};

struct B : A {

    template <typename T>
    void print(T& t){ 
        // do sth specific for B
    }
};
```

In such case, the more general Base class with virtual functions (which A and B both inherit from) cannot be compiled, since there is no virtual for template. As I try to delegate generally all A or B objects under same "interface", does anyone has the idea to resolve such problem? Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, 
Jun

Comment: What is your question? This code will compile.

Comment: This code is totally compiled, but my question is how to use single pointer to different A or B objects. For example: A* a; to delegate either A or B object, like a abstract factory. But since I cannot use a general virtual abstract class for both A or B class, I'm just left no choice.

Comment: I think in that generality you cannot do it. That is, you cannot have a single base class `B` such that for "B * x;` you can say `x->foo(T1, T2, ...);` and have `foo()` dispatched dynamically.

Comment: Sadly, I just don't like the solution "type field" mentioned in TCPL, it's not elegant :-D, anyway if no solution can be found, i'll do so :-(

Comment: I don't really know your real requirements. I'm half-way through typing something about CRTP, but I'm not sure if it applies to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can think about using using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Static_polymorphism).

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
  template <typename T>
  void print(T& t){ 
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->print(t);
  }
};

struct A : Base<A> {
// template print
};

struct B : Base<B> {
// template print
};
```

Example Usage:

```
template<typename T, typename ARG>
void foo (Base<T>* p, ARG &a)
{
  p->print(a);
}
```

This method will be called as,

```
foo(pA, i); // pA is A*, i is int
foo(pB, d); // pB is B*, d is double
```

Here is [another demo code](http://www.ideone.com/xZBQg).

Answer (score 2):

Using a proxy class to get B's method

```
  class A {
    public:
        friend class CProxyB;
        virtual CProxyB* GetCProxyB() = 0;
    };

    class B;
    class CProxyB
    {
    public:
        CProxyB(B* b){mb = b;} 
        template <typename T>
        void printB(T& t)
        { 
            mb->print(t);
        }       

        B* mb;
    };

    class B:public A {
    public:
        virtual CProxyB* GetCProxyB(){return new CProxyB(this);};

        template <typename T>
        void print(T& t){ 
            printf("OK!!!!!\n");
        }
    };


    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        A* a = new B;

        CProxyB* pb = a->GetCProxyB();

        int t = 0;
        pb->printB(t);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Option one: Virtualize the method where if the user does not provide an implementation, the Base class' is used.

```c
 
template <typename T>
struct A {
    virtual void print(T& t);
};

template <typename T>
void A::print(T& t) {
    // do sth specific for A
}

template <typename T>
struct B : A {
    virtual void print(T& t);
};

void B::print(T& t) {
    // do sth specific for B
}
```

Option two: Abstract the method where if the user does not provide an implementation, the code will not compile.

```c
 
template <typename T>
struct A {
    virtual void print(T& t)=0;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A {

    virtual void print(T& t){ 
        // do sth specific for B
    }
};
template <typename T>
void B::print(T& t){ 
    // do sth specific for B
}
```

Other than the above mentioned, if you do not make them virtual, the Derived class will Shadow the Base class method and that is most certainly not what you intended. Hence, impossible.

Comment: Since the "T" is a predictor, it cannot be simply moved to class level ... :-D

Comment: @perigee: The "T" is a what...?

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how to use single pointer to different A or B objects.

You can do this without virtual functions per-se. But all you will really be doing is writing an implementation of a V-table and virtual functions.

If I were going to manually implement virtual functions, I would base it all on a Boost.Variant object. The variant would effectively hold the member data for each class. To call a function, you use a variant visitor functor. Each "virtual function" would have its own visitor functor, which would have different overloads of operator() for each of the possible types within the variant.

So you might have this:

```
typedef boost::variant<StructA, StructB, StructC> VirtualClass;
```

You could store any one of those objects in the variant. You would call a "virtual function" on the object like this:

```
VirtualClass someObject(StructA());
boost::apply_visitor(FunctorA(), someObject);
```

The class FunctorA is your virtual function implementation. It is a visitor, defined like this:

```
class FunctorA : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
  void operator()(StructA &arg){
    //Do something for StructA
  }

  void operator()(StructB &arg){
    //Do something for StructB
  }

  void operator()(StructC &arg){
    //Do something for StructC
  }
}
```

Visitors can have return values, which are returned by `apply_visitor`. They can take arguments, by storing the arguments as members of the visitor class. And so forth.

Best of all, if you ever change your variant type, to add new "derived classes", you will get compiler errors for any functors that don't have overloads for the new types.

But to be honest, you should just be using virtual functions.

Comment: Huge work around, brilliant , though a little bit complicated. It's great deal by introducing apply_visitor and variant in boost. I'm being a happy boost user for long time, never discover these kind of usage. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any suggestions for using boost well ? or some advanced tutorials ?

Answer (score 0):

By using [CRTP(Curiously recurring template pattern)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), you can achieve static polymorphsim without virtual.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MSG(msg) cout << msg << endl;

template<class Derived>
class Base{
public:
    void print()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->print();
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        MSG("Derived 1::print");
    }


};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        MSG("Derived 2::print");
    }
};

template<class T>
void callme(Base<T>& p)
{
     p.print();
}

int main() 
{
    Base<Derived1> p1;
    Base<Derived2> p2;
    callme(p1);
    callme(p2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Result :
//Derived 1::print
//Derived 2::print
```